# Get property of generic type

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

In our angular6 project we activated the `"noImplicitAny": true` setting and found out that this gave some problems on retrieving a value from generic types.

At the moment we retrieve the value by `current['orderBy']`, but this gives the following error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.`

We can solve this by casting current to any `(<any>current)['orderBy']`, but this is in our eyes worse coding.

We've tried to cast 'orderBy' `current['orderBy' as keyof T]`, but this not nice code and gives the retrieved property the wrong type (`:T[keyof T]`) which in this case makes it impossible to use in calculations (in this case it should be of type number)

We've also tried to make a function were you can pass the generic type and the name of the property we want to get the value of (found here https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/06/typescript-2-1-keyof-and-lookup-types).

`export const prop = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) => {
  return obj[key];
};`

which works if `current` was not a generic type, but it is so it gives the following error: `Argument of type '"orderBy"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof T'`.

So does anyone know another way to retrieve the property value of a generic type that might work? 
(also in this case it is orderBy we tried to retrieve but it could be any other field of the generic type)

Comment: Could you include a full example ? what is the type of `current` ? If it is a generic type what is the type constraint of it ?

Comment: `current` can be 1 of the 300 interfaces we have in the project, I'll try to make a small project with the different things we tried.

Comment: I added an answer that is generally applicable. If you have something more specific I'd be glad to have a look :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unconstrained type parameter, typescript will not let you access any properties of the type since it does not know such accesses are valid. Without `noImplictAny` this worked as you could access any property of any type.

With no implicit any, you will need to be more explicit about what properties your generic type has and what their possible types are:

```
class Foo<T extends { orderBy: string }> {
    m(current: T) {
        let o = current['orderBy']; // string
        let o2 = current.orderBy; // or just . notation
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes and we cant be more explicit as there is no guaranty all interfaces that use the Foo class contain the orderBy field (in our code we try to retrieve it by a string that is set in the class that extends Foo).
I guess we should just remove the noImplictAny again as it gives more issues than we try to solve :)

Comment: @Youri it's your call.. The contraint to for `T` need to describe the widest possible type. It can be for example `{ orderBy? : any} `. So it's optional and can be anything